# Delphi Unidac MySQL Create Trigger From Memo Code Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, delphi, syntax, unidac

Here is my MySQL Trigger code;

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER pdfdenemeu BEFORE INSERT
ON denemetbl
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.iki =  CONCAT(NEW.bir,'.pdf');
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

When i run this code on HeidiSQL it creates trigger and works perfectly.

On Delphi XE7 i'm adding a button and a memo to form, putting this code inside of the memo, and button's onclick event is;

```
sorgu.Close;
sorgu.SQL.Clear;
sorgu.SQL.Add(trim(memo1.text));
sorgu.ExecSQL;
```

When i click to button, it returns syntax error ;
[image: ERROR SCREENSHOT]

Also tried as below;

```
sorgu.Close;
sorgu.SQL.Clear;
sorgu.SQL.Add('DELIMITER //');
sorgu.SQL.Add('CREATE TRIGGER pdfdenemeu BEFORE INSERT');
sorgu.SQL.Add('ON denemetbl');
sorgu.SQL.Add('FOR EACH ROW');
sorgu.SQL.Add('BEGIN');
sorgu.SQL.Add('SET NEW.iki =  CONCAT(NEW.bir,''.pdf'');');
sorgu.SQL.Add('END//');
sorgu.SQL.Add('DELIMITER ;');
sorgu.Execute;
```

As i mentioned trigger code works without any error on HeidiSQL and MySQL command line, why i'm getting this error message, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I guess that `DELIMITER` setting is specific to HeidiSQL.

Comment: @Olivier i tried without delimeter but still returned the same error

Comment: Not possible. The error explicitly mentions `DELIMITER`.

Comment: exactly, but let me try again, i'll keep you posted

Comment: Or maybe you should change the `DELIMITER` in a first query, execute `CREATE TRIGGER` in a second, and restore the `DELIMITER` in a third.

Comment: solved the problem, when i thought i tried without delimeter i wasn't actually, just realised i wrote the code without delimeter but called memo1 content instead of my new trial code, sometimes you need to get away from screen 5 minutes to figure it out huh. Thanks for your suggestion removed the delimeter and worked just fine.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). In any IDE-displayed exception dialog, pressing Ctrl+C will generate a text representation of the dialog in the clipboard, which can then be pasted as text into your post.

Comment: @KenWhite ok, noted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @olivier mentioned DELIMETER is specific to HeidiSQL, i tried to remove delimeter and tried again but didn't solved the problem, but what i did was call the old code with delimeter from my new code, when i thought i removed the delimeter but i wasn't.

So as @olivier mentioned in first post's comment i changed query to this;

```
CREATE TRIGGER pdfdenemeu BEFORE INSERT ON denemetbl FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET NEW.iki= CONCAT(NEW.bir,'.pdf'); END;
```

Worked perfectly.
@olivier Thank you, i owe you one.